# MP3 Headers missing - ffmpeg (mp3 to raw format)

Tags: c, ffmpeg, mp3, codec

I have been trying to decode an MP3 file to raw format, using ffmpeg C library but most of the files return the following error:

```
[mp3 @ 0x7fb922008400] Header missing
```

The code is picked up from examples encoding_decoding.c:

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#define AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE 20480
#define AUDIO_REFILL_THRESH 4096

static void audio_decode_example(const char *outfilename, const char *filename)
{
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int len;
    FILE *f, *outfile;
    uint8_t inbuf[AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
    AVPacket avpkt;
    AVFrame *decoded_frame = NULL;
    av_init_packet(&avpkt);

    /* find the mpeg audio decoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MP3);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    outfile = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
    if (!outfile) {
        av_free(c);
        exit(1);
    }
    /* decode until eof */
    avpkt.data = inbuf;
    avpkt.size = fread(inbuf, 1, AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE, f);
    while (avpkt.size > 0) {
        int i, ch;
        int got_frame = 0;
        if (!decoded_frame) {
            if (!(decoded_frame = av_frame_alloc())) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio frame\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        len = avcodec_decode_audio4(c, decoded_frame, &got_frame, &avpkt);

        if (len < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while decoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (got_frame) {
            /* if a frame has been decoded, output it */
            int data_size = av_get_bytes_per_sample(c->sample_fmt);

            if (data_size < 0) {
                /* This should not occur, checking just for paranoia */
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to calculate data size\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            for (i=0; i<decoded_frame->nb_samples; i++)
            {
                for (ch=0; ch<c->channels; ch++)
                    fwrite(decoded_frame->data[ch] + data_size*i, 1, data_size, outfile);
            }
        }
        avpkt.size -= len;
        avpkt.data += len;
        avpkt.dts =
        avpkt.pts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
        if (avpkt.size < AUDIO_REFILL_THRESH) {
            /* Refill the input buffer, to avoid trying to decode
             * incomplete frames. Instead of this, one could also use
             * a parser, or use a proper container format through
             * libavformat. */
            memmove(inbuf, avpkt.data, avpkt.size);
            avpkt.data = inbuf;
            len = fread(avpkt.data + avpkt.size, 1,
                        AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE - avpkt.size, f);
            if (len > 0)
                avpkt.size += len;
        }
    }
    fclose(outfile);
    fclose(f);
    avcodec_close(c);
    av_free(c);
    av_frame_free(&decoded_frame);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* register all the codecs */
    avcodec_register_all();
    char *src_filename = "adele.mp3";
    audio_decode_example("adele.pcm", src_filename);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried doing this av_read_frame but get the same error. Any hints on how can I proceed from here or if I am making a mistake that needs to be corrected? (Same file gets decoded properly using ffmpeg commandline)